# How to know current working directory in sftp from python

Tags: python, operating-system, sftp, paramiko

I had connected to sftp with some details to fetch some files with paramiko from python
and code is below

```
import paramiko
import os
import ftplib

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy( paramiko.AutoAddPolicy() )
ssh.connect('sftp.example.com', username='user', password='pass')
ftp = ssh.open_sftp()
files = ftp.listdir()
print files,"----< Total files"
print ftp.cwd(),"---< Current working diectory"

for feedFile in files:
    if feedFile == 'LifeBridge':
        ftp.chdir(feedFile)
```

**Result**

```
['Emerson', 'Lehighvalley', 'LifeBridge', 'stmaryct'] ----< Total files

File "test_sftp.py", line 11, in <module>
    print ftp.cwd()   ---< Current working diectory
AttributeError: 'SFTPClient' object has no attribute 'cwd'
```

here what i am doing is

1. Trying to find the current working directory of sftp
2. There is a list of files above  which i got as a result for printing files, i am trying to check whether they are folders or files,
   If they are folders i want to enter in to  `LifeBridge` folder

Finally can anyone let me know the following

1. how to check the current working directory of sftp
2. how to check whether result from the above list is a file or a folder

Comment: have you checked if there is a `getcwd` attribute available for the object `ftp`

Comment: Thanks for reply, no i had tried just now and thats returning none. in the sense no directory has set right?. And how to know the data in the above list mentioned in the code is a file or a folder

Answer (score 11):

You are looking for the [`.getcwd()` method](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/docs/paramiko.SFTPClient-class.html#getcwd) instead:

> Return the "current working directory" for this SFTP session, as emulated by paramiko. If no directory has been set with `chdir`, this method will return `None`.

So at the start of your session, if you need the current working dir, try a `.chdir('.')` (change to current directory) first.

The `.listdir()` method only returns names of items in the directory. If you need more information about those files, you'd need to use the [`.listdir_attr()` method](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/docs/paramiko.SFTPClient-class.html#listdir_attr) instead, it returns a list of [`SFTPAttributes` instances](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/docs/paramiko.SFTPAttributes-class.html).

An `SFTPAttributes` instance tells you what mode the file has, through the `.st_mode` attribute. Use the [`stat.S_ISDIR(mode)` function](http://docs.python.org/library/stat.html#module-stat) to test if the file is a directory.

Comment: Thanks for replying, yes its returning none so no directory has been set. And how to find the data in the list is a file or folder